# Top positioning in different browsers

Tags: css

I'm working on a `input text with image` and I'm trying to position the image on the right side corner of the input text and it seems that my `top` positioning has different output in different browsers. So I have this HTML structure like so:

```
   <div class="bcb-box-left-content">
      <input type="text" name="skills" id="skills"/>
      <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/plus-in-box.png" alt=""/></a>
      <p>Maxiumum 3 skills for a guest account.</p>
   </div>
```

And here is the style for that:

```
   /*----the parent container-----------*/

  .bcb-box-left-content 
   { 
    max-width:444px;  
    margin-left:17px; 
    position:relative;
    margin-right:20px;}

   /**********the anchor *********/

   .bcb-box-left-content a
    {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 4px;
    top:5px;
    }

   /**********the input text *********/

   #skills { 
    width:100%;  padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
   }
```

So now is there any approach like this (but not literally the code itself):

```
  /*in this case TOP for chrome*/
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(57,72,83,1); 

  /*in this case TOP for mozilla*/
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(57,72,83,1);

  /*in this case TOP for normal*/
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(57,72,83,1);
```

**DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/leonardeveloper/Wm4ML/

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai Check the link above I updated it. Try it in `Chrome`, `Firefox` , `Safari` even if they have just a little differences.

Comment: I have given my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `margin` and default `border` property to your `#skills` class. It will give the same result on all the browsers as you mentioned. Update your CSS like below.

```
 #skills 
 { 
    width:100%;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px; 
    margin:0; 
    border:1px solid #ccc;  
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wm4ML/5/)